How to get only 1 day's data of videos in my youtube channel using Youtube Reporting API
I am trying to get the User activity channel report for my YouTube channel using the Youtube Reporting API by following this documentation - https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports#video-user-activity
The first step is to create a job with reportType as channel_basic_a2.The job generates reports for the past 30 days. According to the documentation, the reports will be generated within 48 hours as per documentation. I was looking for a way to limit the number of days from 30 to 1, which may reduce the time to generate the reports. Is there a way we can send the number of days as a parameter in the API request?
I am using this code sample present in YouTube Reporting API documentation -
https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs.reports/list

There are two params, startTimeAtOrAfter and startTimeBefore. Setting them properly you should be able to filter a specific day

That works! There is a difference of around 3 hours between createdAt value of 1st report (1 day before) and the last report(30 days before). Using startTimeAtOrAfter, I can filter the reports I want, which can save some time. Thanks @pierpy

Glad to help...
